# KeyError at /accounts/regist/

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I got an error:

> KeyError at /accounts/regist/ 'email'.

Before, my user registration form had username&password column only. I want to add email form into it, so I wrote it. But I got the error. I imported:

```
django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm.
```

And my auth_user table has email column , so I do not know how to fix it.
I wrote in test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
class UserTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """
        setUp for testing
        """
        User.objects.create(username='user1', email='email1', password='user1')
        User.objects.create(username='user2', email='email2',password='user2')
        self.user1 = User.objects.get(username='user1')
        self.user2 = User.objects.get(username='user2')
```

in serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username','email', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fields = ('id')

        def create(self, validated_data):
          password = validated_data.get('password')
          validated_data['password'] = make_password(password)
          return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

In these codes,I designated email column.So,what should I do to fix it?

Traceback shows

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
  39          response = get_response(request) 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
187         response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
185        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
accounts/views.py in regist
65         form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None) 
▶ Local vars
accounts/forms.py in __init__
11      self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control' 
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: You need to show the actual test case, the view, and the full traceback.

Comment: The [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) doesn't have an email field, I don't understand what you hope to achieve by adding one? Do you need to override djangos?

Comment: @Sayse thx, ur comments.I wanna add email authentication system.Now my app has username&password  authentication system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your partial stacktrace, your code is choking when attempting to define the widget for the email field. But where is that field defined? It's not defined anywhere. Your code should change as:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
```